# What is the difference between Cyberpunk and Futuristic games (scenario based)?

Tags: terminology

I can definitely tell which game titles are each, but I can't define what Cyberpunk and Futuristic are outside of them. Is Cyberpunk future in the city, and Futuristic future in space, or what?

Comment: I might help to give some more context on why you want to know this.

Comment: I'm game developer workingin a cyberpunk project which is getting a little out of concept (we're designing having mission in space) which I am against because it misses the cyberpunk context although I have a hard time explaining it.

Comment: I think futuristic is, obviously, a sort of advanced but modern looking setting. Think of things where everything is automatic and those bright white metals with sleek flowing designs. And then cyberpunk on the other hand is similar but just dirtier. Worn down and not as bright. It's like the inner city version of a futuristic society. EDIT: Another thing i feel is commonly attributed to cyberpunk but not futuristic is things like biotic modifications so think Bioshock in that sense.

Comment: Pretty much by definition a cyberpunk setting is also a futuristic setting. Futuristic is a very, very broad category, so it won't help you with focusing your game's concept. You might want to draw a distinction between "space opera" and "cyberpunk". Stars Wars is the modern prototype for space opera, so could represent the direction you don't want your game to go.

Comment: If this goes beyond gaming, you could also ask on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my question is specific in gaming context

Comment: I personally fell that cyberpunk and futuristic are not neccesarly mutually exclusive. Something has to be futuristic to be cyberpunk, but something doesn't have to be cyberpunk to be futuristic. Some frogs are toads, but all toads are frogs.

Comment: I also feel this is a legit question, and doesn't deserve the amount of downvotes it's getting. Although this does belong more on scifi.se than here, this question has nothing to do with games, even though he's asking for gaming reasons.

Comment: [Genre definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre) are inherently subjective and a matter of debate and opinion. Even when they can be pinned down, they change over time.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia:

#### [Cyberpunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk)

> Cyberpunk is a subgenre of science fiction in a future setting, noted for its focus on "high tech and low life". It features advanced science, such as information technology and cybernetics, coupled with a degree of breakdown or radical change in the social order.

#### [Futuristic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/futuristic)

> 1. of or relating to the future :
>      a futuristic view of the world.
> 2. ahead of the times; advanced:
>      futuristic technology.
> 3. (sometimes initial capital letter) of or relating to futurism :
>      the futuristic rejection of traditional forms.

---

In summary, "futuristic" is a very broad description that includes everything that is somewhat related to the future, including cyberpunk.

Cyberpunk on the other hand describes a mix between advanced technology and social decline.

Answer (score 2):

Futuristic just means that it has the appearance of coming from the future. A futuristic game would have at least some significant element, usually technology but potentially other things, that you can only imagine existing in the future. For example, while all Star Wars games are set "a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away" they contain numerous things like light sabers, dogfighting spacecraft, and talking robots, that you can only imagine existing in the real world at some point in the future. Even a post-apocalyptic setting where technology actually regressed — a fairly popular genre right now — might be called futuristic because we can only imagine them taking place in the future.

The cyberpunk genre was pretty well defined by Nolonar, and I'm sure you've got a good understanding about what it is, so I won't give my own definition. But it should be fairly clear from the above that pretty much any cyberpunk setting also counts as being futuristic. In addition to futuristic technology like cybernetics, the cyberpunk settings also contain social changes that we can — with a suitably pessimistic world view — imagine our own society ending up resembling in the future.